# Flutter - Drawer slide area expand

Tags: flutter

I have drawer on flutter project. how do i expand the drawer slide area?

[I want to slide within the area up to the red ground](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6jlq.png)

Comment: are you asking how to increase the width of the drawer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can drawerEdgeDragWidth

```
return Scaffold(
...
  drawerEdgeDragWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
...
);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better if you help us with your code. But if i gotten your question, you can expand your drawer to the width you need.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      bottom: false,
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius:
          BorderRadius.only(
            topRight: Radius.circular(35.0),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(35.0),),
        child: Container( //wrap the drawer with a container
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.30, // -> 30% of the screen
          child: Drawer(
               child: ListView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),
                children: <Widget>[ 
                    //Your drawer items
                ],
              ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

And the result will be this.[image]